# How do I fix this corner?

Tags: bathroom, walls, moisture, rot

I am trying to fix up the bathroom in my new apartment before I move in. The rest of it is bad, but not like this. It was duct taped in so I assume moisture got behind there and destroyed it. There was initially mold in the bathroom which proves that point. There is big chunks of solid wall, wood, and other random things falling out of the hole. I don’t have a whole lot of experience renovating things and I think this is above my skill level. How would I even go about repairing this?[4 pictures of a wall corner with rotten wood falling out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8l92g.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8l92g.jpg)

Comment: Is the apartment a rental or bought unit?  If rental the landlord should take care of it(maybe with a bit of help from local health department).  If bought read the sales contract over carefully(maybe with help from a lawyer).  Undiscourse known damage might be a thing in your location.

Comment: Invite 2 or 3 handyman to give you a quote and explain the work they will do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that water infiltration is not a problem anymore:

1. Remove all of the crumbling pieces of dried joint compound.
2. Install a new piece of sheetrock with screws.
3. Install a new corner bead.
4. Apply joint compound in stages (look up a YouTube tutorial).
5. Sand.
6. Apply primer.
7. Paint.

Superficial mold spots are common in bathrooms, because of the humidity.

This is all assuming that this is your apartment and that you bought it for a great price. If this is a rental, have the landlord fix this. If the landlord refuses, the local health department will probably want to have a word with him/her.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! That sounds like surprisingly less work than I was expecting. Do you know if I can get everything I need from Lowes for this project? I am renting this place from a landlord and he’s sort of making me do all of the repairs and taking the supplies off of my rent. I am starting to wonder if it would be cheaper (or easier lol) to just hire someone to fix that up. There are other spots with rot in the bathroom that have been very poorly covered up as well.

Comment: Getting reimbursed for supplies is a terrible deal for you. Unless the rent is a steal, say 50% off market, tell your landlord to call a handyman himself. Your job as a tenant ends with paying the damn rent. You're not your landlord's concierge or bank. WTF, man.